# inconsistent error while running spider in Scrapy Cloud

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy

I'm fairly new to this and been looking into spiders/crawlers for about a week now.

I've been setting up spiders in Scrapy. Launched my first finished spider yesterday. Everything seems to run smooth, except for this one error that pops up now and then.

The following error is received in 4 jobs but not on the same page (or time) in the spider:

```
next_page_url = response.css('div.indexering > a::attr(href)').extract()[-1]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

These are the jobs and when the error appeared:

```
Job 1: 
39: 2017-09-27 09:00:03 ERROR [scrapy.core.scraper] Spider error processing <GET https://www.baby-dump.be/zoeken/?zoek=*/&pnr=102> (referer: [https://www.baby-dump.be/zoeken/?zoek=*/&pnr=101][1])

Job 2:
46: 2017-09-27 10:00:05 ERROR [scrapy.core.scraper] Spider error processing <GET https://www.baby-dump.be/zoeken/?zoek=*/&pnr=98> (referer [https://www.baby-dump.be/zoeken/?zoek=*/&pnr=97][1])

Job 3:
55: 2017-09-27 12:00:07 ERROR [scrapy.core.scraper] Spider error processing <GET https://www.baby-dump.be/zoeken/?zoek=*/&pnr=159> (referer: [https://www.baby-dump.be/zoeken/?zoek=*/&pnr=158][1])

Job 4:
18: 2017-09-27 14:00:11 ERROR [scrapy.core.scraper] Spider error processing <GET https://www.baby-dump.be/zoeken/?zoek=*/&pnr=22> (referer: [https://www.baby-dump.be/zoeken/?zoek=*/&pnr=21][1])
```

It looks like the expected 'Next' button (for which the spider is looking) wasn't found if I interpret the error correctly.

This can't be because if you look at the jobs, the error is inconsistent. It appears at random times.

Edit: added the piece of code where the error occurs below.

```
def parse(self, response):
    #get all product detail pages links
    urls = response.css('div.product-image > a::attr(href)').extract()
    for url in urls:
        url = response.urljoin(url)
        yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse_details)

    #get next page and follow
    next_page_url = response.css('div.indexering > a::attr(href)').extract()[-1]
    if next_page_url:
        next_page_url = response.urljoin(next_page_url)
        yield scrapy.Request(url=next_page_url, callback=self.parse)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is mostly when the next page is not there at all. So probably on the last page? You should change the code to below so you know if the last page was there or not

```
next_page_url = response.css('div.indexering > a::attr(href)')

if next_page_url:
   next_page_url = next_page_url.extract()[-1]
else:
   next_page_url = ""
```

Comment: Hi Tarun, thanks for your answer. The if statement is added (without the else) in the code already. The page also looks to be present because in the log you see that the url page is incremented and then followed. Could it have something to do with the spider crawling too fast for the 'next page' object?
I added the piece of code where the error will most likely occur to the original post.

Comment: The issue is that when you execute `response.css('div.indexering > a::attr(href)').extract()` , it could lead to a blank/no-data and you use `[-1]` always, without checking if the results are there or not. That is what I have changed in my code.

Comment: I see now what you meant. Thanks for the help! This fixed my issue.